# Developing a Multiplatform script that makes symbolic links

Tags: bash, unix, symlink, shared, multiplatform

I've had this issue for many days. I've tried hard to find a solution but couldn't find one, so I felt like sharing this with experts to get suggestions. So here is my issue.

We have multiprotocol shared drives that are mounted in a Unix environment in some location `/cs/gat/mnt`.

I have written a shell script that creates symlinks of these shared drives. Similarly, I have written a Windows bash script that creates the same symlinks on a Windows shared drive as well. Both work well if run in their environment.

Now, I want to make a compact script, so that directly running it would create symlinks in both Windows and Unix environment.

Please advise me the best way to do so in detail. Much appreciate your advice.

Comment: which is the target OS for your new script?

Comment: Either platform would be fine for me. I guess, preparing a windows platform script would be better approach.

Comment: Is Windows supporting symbolic links at all? At least FAT32 wasn't able to.

Comment: @frlan: NTFS actually supports symlinks - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Comment: I used mklink commands to create links. It worked well.

Comment: write a python script and call them in it

Comment: @obayhan: Please elaborate the way to do it.